# assigning acl to a group in configuration

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]

how do i assign permissions to a magento 2 configuration group

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to check this myself, but from looking into the core code, you need to add it as a resource in acl.xml. `Magento_CatalogSearch` has an example of that. An additional resource is specified for the Catalog Search Group (in the Catalog Section).

Since you can't specify a resource for a group, you would use the parent sections resource id, and append the group id. Like this (using Magento_CatalogSearch as an example):

```
<resource id="Magento_CatalogSearch::config_catalog_search" title="Catalog Search" translate="title" sortOrder="10" />
```

The parent sections acl resource id is `Magento_Catalog::config_catalog`. The groups id (in system.xml) is `search`. So that's where the child groups resource id of `Magento_CatalogSearch::config_catalog_search` comes from. Then, the groups title (again, from system.xml) is specified as the title in acl.xml.

For reference, look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/acl.xml` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`.